# Vue add i18n returns ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'minVersion' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, vue-i18n

I try to run vue cli `vue add i18n` to generate localisation using i18n to my local. It got error

```
Done in 37.95s.

    ✔  Successfully installed plugin: vue-cli-plugin-i18n
    
     ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'minVersion' of undefined
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'minVersion' of undefined
        at module.exports.pkg (/mnt/disks/data_disks/teja/localised/forexsignals/node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-i18n/prompts.js:5:26)
        at invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/invoke.js:74:25)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

The `i18n.js` and other files aren't generated.

Otherwise, I want to try to add i18n manually using `npm install` then add the files manually, but stuck at editing `vue.config.js`, here below my `vue.config.js` shown

```
    var PrerenderSpaPlugin = require('prerender-spa-plugin')
    var path = require('path')
    var Renderer = PrerenderSpaPlugin.PuppeteerRenderer;
    
    
    module.exports = {
      configureWebpack: config => {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') return
    
        return {
          plugins: [
            new PrerenderSpaPlugin(
              {
                staticDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
                routes: ['/', '/join-free-channel'],
                renderer: new Renderer({
                  headless: true
                })
              }
            ),
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

I have installed prerendering for my vue app that updates my `vue.config.js` file, but still have no idea about how to add internationalisation to the app by editing `vue.config.js`

Answer (score 2):

I recently had this problem, this is caused by the absence of the **@vue/cli-shared-utils** dependency. I'm not sure why it was not installed when installing **vue-cli**.

A quick solution to this problem is to install this dependency: `npm i @vue/cli-shared-utils`

After installing, run `vue add i18n` again and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. I saw this error after `vue add i18n`, but I think they are the same

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

So, I just removed the `package-lock.json` file and then executed `vue add i18n` again.

It worked for me.